# Is there an analog of \unskip for vertical mode?

Tags: spacing

I'm gluing together a bunch of code fragments using \verbatiminput, and I want to eliminate the vertical space (glue) that would normally come between the fragments.  But I cannot use `\unskip` because that is for horizontal mode only.

Is there an analog of `\unskip` (remove the last item on the current list if it is glue) for vertical mode?

For those who requested an example:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}

...

\verbatiminput{one}
\verbatiminput{two}
\verbatiminput{three}
```

I'd like to remove the extra spacing inserted between successive calls to `\verbatiminput`.

Comment: Well, `\unskip` works in internal vertical mode. So maybe putting stuff into a `\vbox`, unskipping to your heart's content, and then `\unvbox`ing would be an alternative?

Comment: Further possibility: `\vskip-\lastskip`. LaTeX offers a command `\removelastskip` to that effect.

Comment: Could you please make an example?

Answer (score 18):

As noted in the comments `\unskip` works in vertical mode if you are in a box. Or you can `\vskip-\lastskip` but better really is just not to add the space in the first place.

LaTeX's `\addvspace` tries to avoid adding space necessarily, it works like `\vspace` or `vskip` unless space was recently added. (This is so two consecutive display environments do not get double space in the middle.) Perhaps you want `\nointerlineskip` or `offinterlineskip` so TeX does not automatically add skip before the vertical material that you are adding,

Answer (score 8):

You can try checking whether a `\verbatiminput` follows and, in this case, remove the skips that are inserted (twice `\topsep`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@input#1#2{%
   \IfFileExists {#2}{\@verbatim #1\relax
    \verbatim@readfile{\@filef@und}\endtrivlist\endgroup\@doendpe}%
   {\typeout {No file #2.}\endgroup}%
   %% Added code
   \@ifnextchar\verbatiminput{\vspace{-2\topskip}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{beer}
\verbatiminput{beer}
This is no beer.
\verbatiminput{beer}
This is no beer.
\end{document}
```

Here is `beer.tex`:

```
\let~\catcode~`x13~`q~`x~`z~`q~`H~`q~`B~`H~`j0~`jA009
jlet~jlet~Hjpar ~Bjmscount~~jdef~x{q bottlez of beer}
~jw{x on the wall}~jt{jadvanceAB-1ATake one down Aand
pass it around,H}B99~ji{jifnumB}~q{ji=0Nojelsejnumber
Bjfi}~z{ji>1sjfiA }jloop jifnumB>0 jw, x,Hjtjw.jvskip
8ptplus1ptjrepeat Time to buy some more beerjdotsjend
```

---

Perhaps, a better solution is to use a different command, let's call it `\multiverbatiminput` that accepts a list of file names:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\def\multiverbatiminput{\begingroup
  \@ifstar{\multiverbatim@input\relax}%
          {\multiverbatim@input{\frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces}}}
\def\multiverbatim@input#1#2{%
  \@verbatim #1\relax
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \IfFileExists{\next}{\verbatim@readfile{\@filef@und}}
                        {\typeout {No file \next.}}}%
  \endtrivlist\endgroup\@doendpe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is beer
\multiverbatiminput{beer,beer}
Also this is
\multiverbatiminput{beer}
This is no beer.
\end{document}
```