# Stop LyX from automatically wrapping formulas with LRE (in Hebrew)

Tags: lyx, automation, hebrew

As in [the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610036/bidi-lre-command-causes-too-much-vertical-space-if-put-at-end-of-an-item-in-a-li), I'm working in LyX in Hebrew, by using the "use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)" option. When I insert a math equation LyX automatically wraps it with `\LRE{}`. This causes some problems with spacing and has no benefits (formulas also look just fine without it). Is there a way to tell LyX to stop automatically adding `\LRE{}` around equations?

Comment: If you put `\renewcommand{\LRE}[1]{#1}` in your preamble (Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble), does that do what you want (check the PDF output)? I don't believe it's easy to stop LyX from inserting LRE. If you happen to be on Linux I don't think it would be too difficult to stop LyX from inserting LRE in the source code and recompile.

Comment: @scottkosty that seems to cancel the \LRE command altogether. However I do want it to apply when I combine English text in my file. Is there a way to remove it from the equations only?

Comment: Ah I understand now. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it i not possible from preventing LyX from enclosing equations with `\LRE`, it might be fixed in the future.

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to avoid some vertical spacing the the `\LRE` is causing when surrounding display equations. The following code will redefine `\LRE` to check if the first token of its argument is `\[`, if so it will do nothing, otherwise it will behave as usual (note that it will cause problems in situations like `\textenglish{\[a+b=c\] Hello there}`, but I don't think there is a situation where you need to type something like that).

```
\long\def\LRE@gobble#1#2\stopgobblehere{#1}
\AddToHook{package/bidi/after}{%
    \bidi@renewrobustcmd*{\LRE}[1]{%
        \expandafter\ifx\LRE@gobble #1{}{}\stopgobblehere\[
        #1%
        \else
        \protect\pLRE{#1}%
        \fi
    }%
}
```

In LyX you should add that to `Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble`.

Another possibility is using expl3 syntax

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\AddToHook{package/bidi/after}{%
    \bidi@renewrobustcmd*{\LRE}[1]
    {
        \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
        \tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_tmpa_tl { \[ }
            { #1 }
            { \protect\pLRE{#1} }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You can add a conditional for inline equation, but I don't think `\LRE` i causing spacing problems around inline equations.